# Errors when including hyphens in table variables

Tags: lua

I recently bought MaterialBoard from ScriptFodder. I am editing the groups list so it will show the capitalized & un-hyphened group names so instead of head-admin it would look like "Head Admin". Everything has worked so far but once it started using hyphens in the variable name, it concluded errors:

```
[ERROR] addons/materialboard/lua/matboard_config.lua:76: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 73) near '='
    1. unknown - addons/materialboard/lua/matboard_config.lua:0
```

how do I make it so I can include hyphens in a table variable name like this?

```
co-owner   = "Co-Owner",
```

Answer (score 14):

```
local t = {co-owner = "Co-Owner"}
```

is not valid because `-` cannot be used in an identifier. Instead, use the more general syntax:

```
local t = {["co-owner"] = "Co-Owner"}
print(t["co-owner"])
```